# Switch-Case and user_role

Tags: php, user-roles, customization

I am trying to create a page that shows all users with a selection of details. One of those details is the user role it has. For each role I want to display a different string. In order to achieve this is have the following code:

```
function smoelenboek_func(){
    $users = get_users('orderby=nicename');
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        switch ($user->roles[0]) {
            case 'administrator' :
                echo 'Yes';
            case 'member' :
                echo 'No';
            case 'oldmember' :
                echo 'Maybe';
        };
    };
};
```

Now the strange thing that happens is, users with an administrator role get output "YesNoMaybe", a member role gets "NoMaybe" and oldmember gets "Maybe". Am I using the Switch-Case incorrectly? Is there something in the roles array that I'm misinterpreting? Any help is hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed break statement

This is how switch case works

```
switch ($i) {
    case "apple":
        echo "i is apple";
        break;
    case "bar":
        echo "i is bar";
        break;
    case "cake":
        echo "i is cake";
        break;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is missing break and also your requirement is like below:

If administrator, `YesNoMaybe` OR if member, `NoMaybe` OR if `oldmember`, Maybe.

Finally code is look like Below:

```
function smoelenboek_func(){
    $users = get_users('orderby=nicename');
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        switch ($user->roles[0]) {
            case 'administrator' :
                echo 'YesNoMaybe';
                break;
            case 'member' :
                echo 'NoMaybe';
                break;
            case 'oldmember' :
                echo 'Maybe';
                break;
        };
    };
};
```

I hope this may help you well.

P.S. Let me know if you have any query/concern regarding this.